# VBA word 2016 Колонтитул не инициализируется

Tags: vba, ms-word, макросы

В общем проблема такая, я написал макрос, который вставляет колонтитул и он успешно работает, но перед тем как воспользоваться макросом надо обязательно открыть выпадающее меню (Вставить верхний колонтитул или Вставить нижний колонтитул) и только так макрос будет работать. А если документ .docx только что был создан, то макрос не будет работать пока вы не откроете меню с колонтитулами.
Такой вопрос, есть ли решения для данной проблемы по типу инициализация колонтитулов или прогрузка колонтитулов

```
Sub macr_horiz_A3()
    Dim objTemplate As Template
    Dim objBB As BuildingBlock
    Dim folderPath As String

    ' Загружаем шаблон
    folderPath = Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1049\16\Building Blocks.dotx"
    
    Set objTemplate = Application.Templates(folderPath)
    Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("a3horizontal")
    
    ' Сохраняем текущую позицию курсора
    Dim currentPosition As Range
    Set currentPosition = Selection.Range
    
    ' Меняем формат и колонтитул на текущей странице
    currentPosition.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
    currentPosition.PageSetup.PaperSize = wdPaperA3
    currentPosition.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = ""
    objBB.Insert Where:=currentPosition.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range, RichText:=True
    currentPosition.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
End Sub
```

[image: Скриншот 1, новый документ без открытия меню с колонтитулами]
[image: Скриншот 2, колонтитулы прогрузились и отображены в VBA]
[image: Скриншот 3, результат работы макроса, выполнен без ошибок]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.templates.loadbuildingblocks) перед тем, как обращаться к шаблонам

```
Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
Set objBB = Templates(Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1049\16\Building Blocks.dotx").BuildingBlockEntries("a3horizontal")
```

Comment: Теперь пишет другую ошибку (Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assigment). Я убрал Environ, чтобы запрос файла состоял из 1 аргумента, где-то это увидел, но не помогло. В правильности пути я уверен.
VBA выделяет LoadBuildingBlocks при выводе  ошибки.
Загрузку шаблонов исправил на это:
' Загружаем шаблон
    Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks("C:\Users\P_Egorov\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1049\16\Building Blocks.dotx").BuildingBlockEntries("a3horizontal").Insert Where:=currentPosition.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range, RichText:=True

Comment: Просто напишите отдельной строкой Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks без аргументов

Comment: Дополнил ответ.